# "Coffee/The coffee that is served at this café is delicious." - What are the differences in meaning?

Tags: meaning, articles, definite-article, zero-article

When using a relative clause to modify an uncountable noun, should we include "the" before the noun?

What are the differences in meaning?

**Example 1**

> "**The** coffee that is served at this café is delicious." (with "the")

> "Coffee that is served at this café is delicious." (without "the")

**Example 2**

> "**The** knowledge that she possesses is extensive." (with "the")

> "Knowledge that she possesses is extensive." (without "the")

**Example 3**

> "**The** art that is displayed in the gallery is breathtaking." (with "the")

> "Art that is displayed in the gallery is breathtaking." (without "the")

Comment: There's no semantic difference, but I'd say that all your examples are more likely to include the article than not.

Comment: ... especially Example 2. Without 'the' its claim is vague.

Answer (score 1):

In all three instances, the grammar is correct both ways, but the version with "the" is the natural way to express what you likely intend.

Without "the", the literal meaning is that coffee served in that café is *defined as delicious* by virtue of being served in that cafe. Similarly, any knowledge that she has is considered "extensive", and any art displayed in that gallery is automatically "breathtaking".

Since all of that is nonsense, most competent English speakers would assume a missing "the" without really thinking about it, but notice that it doesn't quite sit right.